# Checking multiple values of a dictionary to verify an answer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I managed to create an input field that is able to be checked and verified upon a question via creating another text field and linking that to said question, so for example if the value of the question was '1', the answer would be '1'. Then I made a text comparison, so that if what the user wrote = that text field the answer would be correct.
However, I realise that sometimes someone can write something else. For example in the question ' What do you think about tigers', there isn't just one possible answer. And therefore, the way I did that for the input field does not exactly work (does it?).

I did quite a lot of research and found out about dictionaries, but since they only have one key value that wouldn't help, and then I found out about lists, which might?

So my question is whether it is possible, and how, to create a list that's integer values is somehow linked to the values of the overarching question, so that if the random value is 1, the list value is 1 as well, and then check if what is written matches any of the answers with that random value.

If what I just said didn't make sense, here's an example:

**Current behavior:**

> SURVEY: Do you like cats?
>
> INPUT FIELD: Yes I do
>
> HIDDEN TEXT FIELD : Yes I do
>
> input field = hidden text field and therefore correct

**Ideal behavior:**

> SURVEY: Do you like cats?
>
> INPUT FIELD: I do like cats
>
> POSSIBLE ANSWERS: I do like cats, Yes I do etc.
>
> INPUT FIELD contains an answer in the list which matches the question and therefore correct.

I thought you could use the `.Contains` function, but I didn't know how to link it all together.

EDIT:

I tried to solve this problem via the creation of a dictionary and searching for a key (which I believe was the right way to do this), but for some reason this code doesn't even work when checking it? (it's like the .containsKey function doesn't work?)

```
public string questions = "hi;weird;by";
Dictionary<int, string> tester = new Dictionary<int, string>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{     
    tester.Add(1, questions);
    tester.Add(2, "hello");
    tester.Add(3, "by");
    tester.Add(4, "hi");
    tester.Add(5, "bye");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{       
}

public void hello ()
{
    if(tester.ContainsKey(2))
    {
        string value = tester[2];
        Debug.Log("Correct");
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

Following what trashr0X said I tried doing it by having a dictionary script in the main camera and a script in the inputfield, but for some reason when I load it nothing works on the console:

**LIST**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;

public class Listpractice : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Dictionary<int, List<string>> tester = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    List<string> possibleAnswersToQuestionZero = new List<string>(); 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        possibleAnswersToQuestionZero.Add("Hello");
        possibleAnswersToQuestionZero.Add("By");
        tester.Add(0, possibleAnswersToQuestionZero);     
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {       
    }

    public void hello ()
    {
        var toCheck = tester[0].FirstOrDefault(x => x == GameController.hello);

        if (toCheck != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hi!");
        }
    } 

}
```

**INPUT FIELD**

```
public class QAClass07
{
    public string Answer = "";
    public string Question = "";
    QAClass07 result = new QAClass07();        
}

public static string hello;   

void Start()
{
  GameObject a = gameObject;   
  hello = a.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text;
}

// registers what the user writes 
public void getInput(string guess)
{        
    // Does something assuming someone enters something
    if (GetComponent<InputField>() != null)
    {
        hello = GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` and then add all the answers to the corresponding question id.

```
var questions = new List<string> { "hi", "weird", "by" };
var tester = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{     
    tester.Add(1, questions);
    tester.Add(2, new List<string> { "hello" });
    tester.Add(3, new List<string> { "by" });
    tester.Add(4, new List<string> { "hi" });
    tester.Add(5, new List<string> { "bye" });
}


public void hello ()
{
    if(tester.ContainsKey(2))
    {
        var answers = tester[2] ?? new List<string>();
        // now you have all answers linked to question with id 2 in answers variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I did quite a lot of research and found out about dictionaries, but since they only have one key value that wouldn't help, and then I found out about lists, which might?"

Yes, a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) does comprise of key-value pairs of a particular type each; you can declare the type of it's key to be `int` (corresponding to the index of the question currently asked), and declare the type of it's value to be `List<string>`, to hold possible answers for that question.

```
// key is question index, value is a list of possible answers for that question
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

// list of possible answers for question 0 (random question number chosen for the example)
var possibleAnswersToQuestionZero = new List<string>(); 
possibleAnswersToQuestionZero.Add("Possible Answer to question 0");
possibleAnswersToQuestionZero.Add("Another possible answer to question 0");

// add that list to the dictionary at key 0.
// you should be also checking if the key exists before trying to access it's value, 
// and what happens if the list returned for that key is null or empty.
dictionary.Add(0, possibleAnswersToQuestionZero);
```

To check if the answer submitted by the user (let's assume it is saved in a variable named `userInput`) for question `0` is in the list of possible answers for that key, we would do:

```
// check if the list at dictionary[0] has at least one instance of userInput,
// otherwise return null
var toCheck = dictionary[0].FirstOrDefault(x => x == userInput);

// if the result is not null, the answer was found 
if (toCheck != null)
{
    // answer found
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just thought unity doesn't use the 'var' function?

Comment: No idea, never used Unity though I don't see a reason why `var` would not be supported. If not, just replace `var` with the type on the RHS of the assignment declaration, i.e. `var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();` becomes `Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();`

Comment: This is what I did to the script + to the script attached to my inputfield, but for some reason it did not work? (as in the console did not log anything:

Comment: Oh, I cannot put my code here...i'll edit my original post so I can show you

Comment: .I edited my original post so you can see what I attempted to do. I guess my problem isn't with the dictionary now but the way in which I am storing what the user is writing in the inputfield

Comment: *"but the way in which I am storing what the user is writing in the inputfield"* => probably best to ask another question for this, so that the focus of this question can be kept to it's original topic: "Checking multiple values of a dictionary to verify an answer"